# what should go into completion in presentViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using `presentViewController` in xcode and not sure what should go into completion.

The code given by xcode documentation:

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

Example that i am using:

```
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:<#^(void)completion#>];
```

What should go into completion?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the below code instead:

```
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:^{ }];
```

or you can simply pass NULL

```
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The completion block is used for doing any tasks after presenting the view controller , the code written inside the completion block will execute only after the view is presented.

Comment: Or to be more idiomatic nil instead of NULL

Comment: NULL is idiomatic for C objects including blocks; see [this example code from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009758-CH1-SW8).

Comment: @CraigMcMahon, `Updated: 2010-08-15`

Comment: Well here's a more recent example then: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Listings/SamplePhotosApp_AAPLRootListViewController_m.html.

Answer (score 16):

@try this

```
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:^{[self animationCompleted];}];


-(void)animationCompleted{

   // Whatever you want to do after finish animation

    NSLog(@"Animation Completed")

}
```

if you don't want to do anything on completion of animation

```
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code for the presenting the view

```
  [[self navigationController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Following is the code for the that

```
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For more detail check the apple [forum discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4443561?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 2.0**

---

*Handle something on completion*

```
viewController.presentViewController(anotherViewController, animated: true, completion: {
    // Whatever you'd like to do when presentViewController completes :)
})
```

*Or do nothing on completion*

```
viewController.presentViewController(anotherViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```